# I think there's more to the "Catholic professors" question than may appear

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/45172/12563), which has to do with the governance of Catholic universities, was closed as "opinion-based"; and yet there's an entire (if brief) [chapter](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2O.HTM) on the subject in the Code of Canon Law, as well as [another](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2R.HTM) describing requirements in canon law for at least some of those teachers. With a little editing to clarify that the question is asking whether the **Church** has any policy on the matter, rather than whether the university does (which seems to me implied by the question itself), I'd like to have it reopened.

**Edit**: I've edited the question to try and focus on the issue of Church law and governance of the university. Let me know if it needs anything further.

Comment: So ANU says that they will not discriminate against an applicant because the person belongs to some other religion. I looked through those canons to see if they had any contrary restrictions, but it seems like the canons only restrict the beliefs of those teaching theology? If the question is about a lecture of a secular discipline I don't see any greater clarity.

Comment: The question was also poor because free will is often less affirmed in Christianity than usually thought. I'd want to see much more details of what was being taught vs what the Church says to prove that the lecturer was actually in conflict with Catholic doctrine.

Comment: @curiousdannii I sort of see what you're saying, but I think the general question (whether and under what circumstances a professor at a Catholic university **must** adhere to Catholic doctrine) is answerable even without those details - especially, as I noted, if the question is strictly about what the Church, rather than the university, allows.

Comment: Yeah, true. The answer might be that there aren't many restrictions on non-theology lecturers, but it would still be a focused answerable question. I'll vote to reopen the edited question then.

Comment: @curiousdannii Take a look now please?

Comment: And it's open again!

Answer (score 4):

I *think* I see your point. But the question need fixing as you describe first...

Closed questions are fair game for editing, even it ends up being a slight adjustment in scope from what the OP was asking, generally an open question serves them better than a closed one. Go ahead and make your suggested tweaks and then vote to re-open. That will put it in the review queue where it can collect more votes to open. Also you can comment here and I'll mod re-open it to speed things up, but I would like the edit to happen before I do that.

Comment: What do you think of it now? I'd like a few people to get a look.

Comment: @Matt It looks like the community voted to re-open before I even got this ping.